# flatten a tibble in dplyr with NAs

Tags: r, dplyr, flatten, tibble

I have the following [tibble](/questions/tagged/tibble) data,

```
 h <- structure(list(label = list(list(structure(list(id = 431676528L, 
    url = "https://api.github.com/repos/emergenzeHack/terremotocentro/labels/per%20sviluppatori", 
    name = "per sviluppatori", color = "d4c5f9", default = FALSE), .Names = c("id", 
"url", "name", "color", "default")), structure(list(id = 442034204L, 
    url = "https://api.github.com/repos/emergenzeHack/terremotocentro/labels/sito%20principale", 
    name = "sito principale", color = "5319e7", default = FALSE), .Names = c("id", 
"url", "name", "color", "default"))), list(structure(list(id = 442051239L, 
    url = "https://api.github.com/repos/emergenzeHack/terremotocentro/labels/mappa", 
    name = "mappa", color = "0052cc", default = FALSE), .Names = c("id", 
"url", "name", "color", "default")), structure(list(id = 431676528L, 
    url = "https://api.github.com/repos/emergenzeHack/terremotocentro/labels/per%20sviluppatori", 
    name = "per sviluppatori", color = "d4c5f9", default = FALSE), .Names = c("id", 
"url", "name", "color", "default")), structure(list(id = 442034204L, 
    url = "https://api.github.com/repos/emergenzeHack/terremotocentro/labels/sito%20principale", 
    name = "sito principale", color = "5319e7", default = FALSE), .Names = c("id", 
"url", "name", "color", "default"))), list(NA_character_)), mainId = c("216226960", 
"215647494", "242390063")), .Names = c("label", "mainId"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I would like to flatten the values from label pairing them with `mainId` so that I can link each sub-element from `labe`l with its *main ID*. I'm trying to get a [tibble](/questions/tagged/tibble) with the headers: `label`,`url`, `name`, `color`, `mainId`.

The solutions for [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48734241/how-to-flatten-a-tibble-in-dplyr) work fine unless there are `NA`s nested in the sub-element of `label`

```
map_df(h, flatten_dfr)
```

> Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : Argument 1 must have names

Comment: Do you want the third `mainID` to be dropped, or have `NA` for the other values?

Comment: @alistaire I would like to have NAs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach that replaces the element just containing `NA_character_` with an list of `NA`s named like the first element of the first row. After that point, `bind_rows` and `unnest` will work normally.

```r
library(tidyverse)

nested_names <- names(pluck(h, 'label', 1, 1))

h2 <- h %>% 
    mutate(label = map(label, map_if, 
                       ~is.null(names(.x)), 
                       ~setNames(rep(list(NA), length(nested_names)), 
                                 nested_names)), 
           label = map(label, bind_rows)) %>% 
    unnest()

h2
#> # A tibble: 6 x 6
#>   mainId           id url                           name     color default
#>   <chr>         <int> <chr>                         <chr>    <chr> <lgl>  
#> 1 216226960 431676528 https://api.github.com/repos… per svi… d4c5… FALSE  
#> 2 216226960 442034204 https://api.github.com/repos… sito pr… 5319… FALSE  
#> 3 215647494 442051239 https://api.github.com/repos… mappa    0052… FALSE  
#> 4 215647494 431676528 https://api.github.com/repos… per svi… d4c5… FALSE  
#> 5 215647494 442034204 https://api.github.com/repos… sito pr… 5319… FALSE  
#> 6 242390063        NA <NA>                          <NA>     <NA>  NA
```

Answer (score 2):

You could first filter out the `mainId`s with missing `label` and then add them back in with a `full_join` (or simply `bind_rows` if your `mainId`s are unique).

```
library(tidyverse)

h_label_missing <- h %>% 
  filter(map_lgl(label, ~all(is.na(.)))) %>% 
  select(-label)

h %>% 
  filter(!map_lgl(label, ~all(is.na(.)))) %>% 
  mutate(label = map(label, bind_rows)) %>% 
  unnest() %>% 
  full_join(h_label_missing, by = "mainId")

# A tibble: 6 x 6
#     mainId         id url                                                                                  name             color  default
#       <chr>     <int> <chr>                                                                                <chr>            <chr>  <lgl>  
# 1 216226960 431676528 https://api.github.com/repos/emergenzeHack/terremotocentro/labels/per%20sviluppatori per sviluppatori d4c5f9 F      
# 2 216226960 442034204 https://api.github.com/repos/emergenzeHack/terremotocentro/labels/sito%20principale  sito principale  5319e7 F      
# 3 215647494 442051239 https://api.github.com/repos/emergenzeHack/terremotocentro/labels/mappa              mappa            0052cc F      
# 4 215647494 431676528 https://api.github.com/repos/emergenzeHack/terremotocentro/labels/per%20sviluppatori per sviluppatori d4c5f9 F      
# 5 215647494 442034204 https://api.github.com/repos/emergenzeHack/terremotocentro/labels/sito%20principale  sito principale  5319e7 F      
# 6 242390063        NA NA                                                                                   NA               NA     NA
```